# Check if a file is an image

Tags: java, image, jai

I am using JAI and create a file with:

```
PlanarImage img = JAI.create("fileload", myFilename);
```

I check before that line if the file exists. But how could I check if the file is a .bmp or a .tiff or an image file?

Does anyone know?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Image Magick project has facilities to identify image and there's a Java wrapper for Image Magick called JMagick which I think you may want to consider instead of reinventing the wheel:

http://www.jmagick.org

I'm using Image Magick all the time, including its "identify" feature from the command line and it never failed once to identify a picture.

Back in the days where I absolutely needed that feature and JMagick didn't exist yet I used to `Runtime.exec()` ImageMagick's `identify` command from Java and it worked perfectly.

Nowadays that JMagick exist this is probably not necessary anymore (but I haven't tried JMagick yet).

Note that it gives much more than just the format, for example:

```
$  identify tmp3.jpg 
tmp3.jpg JPEG 1680x1050 1680x1050+0+0 DirectClass 8-bit 293.582kb 

$  identify tmp.png
tmp.png PNG 1012x900 1012x900+0+0 DirectClass 8-bit 475.119kb
```

Answer (score 4):

Try using the width of the image:

```
boolean isImage(String image_path){
  Image image = new ImageIcon(image_path).getImage();
  if(image.getWidth(null) == -1){
        return false;
  }
  else{
        return true;
  }
}
```

if the width is -1 then is not image.

Comment: Perhaps using `ImageIcon.getIconWidth()` directly would also work? It does, at least, return `-1` if the image was not loaded successfully.

Answer (score 3):

To tell if something is a png, I've used this below snippet in Android java.

```
public CompressFormat getCompressFormat(Context context, Uri fileUri) throws IOException {
    // create input stream
    int numRead;
    byte[] signature = new byte[8];
    byte[] pngIdBytes = { -119, 80, 78, 71, 13, 10, 26, 10 };
    InputStream is = null;

    try {
        ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();
        is = resolver.openInputStream(fileUri);

        // if first 8 bytes are PNG then return PNG reader
        numRead = is.read(signature);

        if (numRead == -1)
            throw new IOException("Trying to reda from 0 byte stream");

    } finally {
        if (is != null)
            is.close();
    }

    if (numRead == 8 && Arrays.equals(signature, pngIdBytes)) {
        return CompressFormat.PNG;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

You could use [DROID](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/droid/index.php?title=Main_Page), a tool for file format identification that also offers a Java API, to be used roughly like this:

```
AnalysisController controller = new AnalysisController();
controller.readSigFile(signatureFileLocation);
controller.addFile(fileToIdentify.getAbsolutePath());
controller.runFileFormatAnalysis();
Iterator<IdentificationFile> it = controller.getFileCollection().getIterator();
```

Documentation on the API usage is rather sparse, but you can have a look at [this working example](http://gforge.planets-project.eu/gf/project/pserv/scmsvn/?action=browse&path=%2F%2Acheckout%2A%2Ftrunk%2FPC%2Fdroid%2Fsrc%2Fmain%2Fjava%2Feu%2Fplanets_project%2Fifr%2Fcore%2Fservices%2Fidentification%2Fdroid%2Fimpl%2FDroid.java&revision=2076&content-type=text%2Fplain&pathrev=2076) (the interesting part is in the `identifyOneBinary` method).

Answer (score 1):

At the beginning of files, there is an identifying character sequence.
For example JPEG files starts with FF D8 FF.

You can check for this sequence in your program but I am not sure whether this works for every file.

For information about identifying characters you can have a look at http://filext.com

Answer (score 0):

The only (semi-)reliable way to determine the contents of a file is to open it and read the first few characters.  Then you can use a set of tests such as implemented in the Unix file command to make an educated guess as to the contents of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Birkan's answer, there is a list of 'magic numbers' available here:

http://www.astro.keele.ac.uk/oldusers/rno/Computing/File_magic.html

I just checked a BMP and TIFF file (both just created in Windows XP / Paint), and they appear to be correct:

```
First two bytes "42 4d" -> BMP
First four bytes "4d 4d 00 2a" -> TIFF
```

I used VIM to edit the files and then did Tools | Convert to Hex, but you can also use 'od -c' or something similar to check them.

As a complete aside, I was slightly amused when I found out the magic numbers used for compiled Java Classes: 'ca fe ba be' - 'cafe babe' :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the standard [JavaBeans Activation Framework](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/javabeans/glasgow/jaf.html) (JAF)

With the JavaBeans Activation Framework standard extension, developers who use Java technology can take advantage of standard services to **determine the type of an arbitrary piece of data**, encapsulate access to it, discover the operations available on it, and to instantiate the appropriate bean to perform said operation(s). For example, if a browser obtained a JPEG image, this framework would enable the browser **to identify that stream of data as an JPEG image**, and from that type, the browser could locate and instantiate an object that could manipulate, or view that image.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(currentImageType ==null){
                    ByteArrayInputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(image);
                    String mimeType = URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromStream(is);
                    if(mimeType == null){
                        AutoDetectParser parser = new AutoDetectParser();
                        Detector detector = parser.getDetector();
                        Metadata md = new Metadata();
                        mimeType = detector.detect(is,md).toString();

                        if (mimeType.contains("pdf")){
                            mimeType ="pdf";
                        }
                        else if(mimeType.contains("tif")||mimeType.contains("tiff")){
                            mimeType = "tif";
                        }
                    }
                    if(mimeType.contains("png")){
                        mimeType ="png";
                    }
                    else if( mimeType.contains("jpg")||mimeType.contains("jpeg")){
                        mimeType = "jpg";
                    }
                    else if (mimeType.contains("pdf")){
                        mimeType ="pdf";
                    }
                    else if(mimeType.contains("tif")||mimeType.contains("tiff")){
                        mimeType = "tif";
                    }

                    currentImageType = ImageType.fromValue(mimeType);
                }
```