# Know if a file is a image in Java/Android

Tags: java, android, image

Given a file path what is the easiest way of know if that file is a image (of any kind) in Java(Android)? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are external tools that can help you do this. Check out [JMimeMagic](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jmimemagic/) and [JMagick](http://www.jmagick.org/index.html). You can also attempt to read the file using the `ImageIO` class, but that can be costly and is not entirely foolproof.

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new FileInputStream(new File(..._)));
```

This question has been asked on SO a couple of times. See these additional threads on the same topic:

[Check if a file is an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192717/check-if-a-file-is-an-image)

[How to check a uploaded file whether it is a image or other file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4169713/how-to-check-a-uploaded-file-whether-it-is-a-image-or-other-file)

Comment: This is *very very bad* in terms of memory and a lot of images would be checked. This can easily cause **OutOfMemoryError**

Answer (score 21):

```
public static boolean isImage(File file) {
    if (file == null || !file.exists()) {
        return false;
    }
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getPath(), options);
    return options.outWidth != -1 && options.outHeight != -1;
}
```

Comment: @MicroR , if you set `options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;` than `BitmapFactory` will not decode whole image's data, but only image's metadata. If file is valid image than `BitmapFactory` will parse metadata and fill `options.outWidth` and `options.outHeight`. These fields will contain width and height of image. If decoding error occur fields will contain -1. See docs http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#outWidth

Answer (score 2):

You can try this code to check more accurately.

```html
  public static boolean isImageFile(String path) {
        String mimeType = URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(path);
        boolean b = mimeType != null && mimeType.startsWith("image");
         if(b){
             return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path) != null;
         }

        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

try this code segment

```
public static boolean isViewableImage(String name) {
    String suffix = name.substring(name.lastIndexOf('.') + 1).toLowerCase();
    if (suffix.length() == 0)
        return false;
    if (suffix.equals("svg"))
        // don't support svg preview
        return false;

    String mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(suffix);
    if (mime == null)
        return false;
    return mime.contains("image");
}
```