# Android: How to check if file is image?

Tags: android, image, listview, imagemagick

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Know if a file is a image in Java/Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9244710/know-if-a-file-is-a-image-in-java-android)

How can I check a file if it is an image?
like following:

if(file.isImage)....

If it's not possible with standard libraries, how can I do it with the MagickImage lib?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: may be you can check with the file extension..

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/9244710/681807

Comment: I think it's not the right way to check with file extension. Because I would have to create a function that checks EVERY image file extensions like bmp, jpg, jpeg, png, gif, tif, etc...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try this code.

```
public class ImageFileFilter implements FileFilter {
   
    private final String[] okFileExtensions = new String[] {
        "jpg",
        "png",
        "gif",
        "jpeg"
    };


    public boolean accept(File file) {
        for (String extension: okFileExtensions) {
            if (file.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(extension)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

It'll work fine.

Use this like
`new ImageFileFilter(pass file name)`;

Comment: That worked... Now I have to search every image extension...

Comment: @ZalaJanaksinh This would return `true` for any file that has an "image file extension", e.g. if I rename `test.mp3` to `test.jpg`, your method would return `true`.

Comment: it's not the right way. Because not all the path includes the image type is  a image

Comment: @AllenVork then suggest what is the right way? && what is the drawback of use of that ?

Comment: try the solution below

Comment: zsxwing's answer works perfectly.

Answer (score 51):

I think if you want to check whether a file is an image, you need to read it. An image file may not obey the file extension rules. You can try to parse the file by [BitmapFactory](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeFile%28java.lang.String,%20android.graphics.BitmapFactory.Options%29) as following:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
if (options.outWidth != -1 && options.outHeight != -1) {
    // This is an image file.
}
else {
    // This is not an image file.
}
```

Comment: But you would need a `try` `catch` right?..

Comment: You can just check the return value of BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);

Comment: options.inJustDecodeBounds = true decrease the parsing time cost since decodeFile will parse only the width and height of the image.

Comment: @zsxwing if are get system file and witch have no permission to decode then get the null pointer excepetion u can`t read this file and create bitmap.and another thing is when u check the multiple file every time to decode and check it`s increase to generate the outofMemory problem.Just think and then reply.

Comment: hmm it says false to every image file...

Comment: @MarcoSeiz then flag my comment direct the right way to some one.

Comment: @zsxwing `decodeFile(String, Options)` will **always** return `null` if you set `inJustDecodeBounds = true`. Use this check to see if it was decoded successfully: `if (options.outWidth != -1 && options.outHeight != -1)`

Comment: This is a right way to check whether a file is image.But it's a waste of time. I want another way to check a file effectively.

Comment: If you can make sure the file extensions are set correctly, checking the file extension name is the most effective way AFAIK.

Comment: "`BitmapFactory.decodeFile()`" great way to kill your app if check includes loads of files

Comment: I think this answer is more complete: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18499840/12980819