# How to check android drawable type?

Tags: android, android-drawable

Can I check the type of drawable at runtime whether it is an xml **shape/selector/layer-list** or **jpg/png/gif** file?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13760269/android-how-to-check-if-file-is-image

Comment: Khan U can set there ids explicitly as tag and then get them when u needed that for example chk this link http://simplyadvanced.net/blog/android-how-to-get-the-drawable-id-for-imageviews/

Answer (score 1):

You can get type of `drawable` with this:

```
public static String getTypeOfDrawable(int drawableId,Context context) {
    Drawable resImg = context.getResources().getDrawable(drawableId);
    return resImg.getClass().toString().replace("class android.graphics.drawable.","");
}
```

You will get result like:

> BitmapDrawable
>
> StateListDrawable

Then you if it is `BitmapDrawable` its not that hard to get format of file