# Use less memory to pass Bitmap to JNI

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface

In Java, I have the user select an image file. I then decode it, covert to PNG, and pass through to JNI.
I suspect that I do not need to copy and allocate so much memory constantly. How can I pare this down? Is there a way I can detect if the image type is JPEG or PNG and not decode & re-encode the bitmap and just pass the original JPEG/PNG data? Or do the conversion with fewer allocations? Right now it is eating up a LOT of memory.

Java:

```
Bitmap yourSelectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
ByteArrayOutputStream outStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
yourSelectedImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream);
byte[] byteData = outStream.toByteArray();

JNILib.PickedImage(byteData);
```

In C, I have the following code for PickedImage:

```
jbyte *b = (jbyte*)env->GetByteArrayElements(data, NULL);
jsize dataSize = env->GetArrayLength(data);
byte* imageData = (byte*)malloc(dataSize);
memcpy(imageData, b, dataSize);
env->ReleaseByteArrayElements(data, b, 0);

imageSelectCallback(imageData, dataSize);
```

Comment: Have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9643228/test-if-file-is-an-image) - it may give you some clues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `java.nio.ByteBuffer` and call the `allocateDirect` function to allocate memory accessible by both Java and C. Then in C, get the pointer to the buffer by doing: `env->GetDirectBufferAddress` and the size of it by doing `env->GetDirectBufferCapacity`.

This way, you only have ONE buffer shared by both sides of the same coin. Both Java and C will be operating on the same image.

So again, read the file into a `java.nio.ByteBuffer` and pass that to C. If C needs a COPY of the image, then you'll have no choice but to allocate 2 buffers (like you are doing now).. I suspect that you don't need a copy and that it's okay for you to modify the buffer given to you by Java..

Comment: What if the C code free()s it? How does Java react?

Comment: You can free it if you allocated it in C if you allocated it in C. Otherwise set all references to it to NULL in JNI/Java code.