# Why is Case-change of JPG to jpg in web project not taking effect?

Tags: html, apache, jsp, netbeans, jpeg

I'm trying to fix a picture display issue and I don't know how to fix it. When I uploaded the files on to my computer some files had extension `.jpg` and others `.JPG`. I rename all the pictures and made sure all extensions were `.jpg`.

Everything seemed to work fine until I created a file path in my web project. I use `<img class="img" alt="" src="${initParam.productGalleryImagePath}${product.id} (1).jpg" />`.

All the pictures that were originally `.jpg` upload fine but all the picture that were originally `.JPG` and converted to `.jpg` won't upload if I use `${initParam.productGalleryImagePath}${product.id} (1).jpg` they will only upload if I use `${initParam.productGalleryImagePath}${product.id} (1).JPG` as if changing them to `.jpg` did not take effect... But with the last statement all the original `.jpg` wont upload.

So it's either `.jpg` to display the `.jpg` or `.JPG` to display the `.JPG`. My IDE is apparently case sensitive. My fear is when I will upload my project to my host... How do I fix this?

Comment: Can you gove some details about your IDE in your question? Is it nix or windows? Apache/ IIS or other?

Comment: @jyoon no they're not!

Comment: On windows they're prob the same but not in nix.

Comment: @CupawnTae Linux treats them differently because case sensitivity.

Comment: @jyoon Also Tomcat even on Windows, and since we're talking jsp here, that's probably pretty relevant

Comment: What did you do to "convert" the images, is it just a changing of the file name? Are the uploaded images finally stored with the '.jpg' extension, and did you check that they are valid images?

Comment: @dewd: The IDE I use is Netbeans so Apache.

Comment: @martinstoeckli: To convert the images I changed the file name and also the extension yes basically only a change of filename.

Comment: @jyoon I think that's what the OP did, and what's causing the issue

Comment: @CupawnTae yes I forgot about that

Comment: @user45678 I think your question title is misleading people into thinking you're asking about file formats. Assuming I've understood your issue correctly I would suggest something like "Case-change of JPG to jpg in web project not taking effect". And add netbeans to your tags, and tomcat if that's what you mean by "apache".

Comment: @CupawnTae: Thanks for the hint. I changed the title.

Answer (score 1):

Case sensitivity is something that you must pay attention to. Technically the files are the same but programmatically  case differences will break your code as you have discovered.

To be safe, its good you check the extension casing and convert all to a fixed form (say `.jpg` or `.JPG`) before you process them further.

Example of such a function is [strtolower()](http://php.net/strtolower) in PHP.

**Update**  Example of code to check if a file is actually an image;

```
function is_image($path)
{
    $a = getimagesize($path);
    $image_type = $a[2];

    if(in_array($image_type, array(IMAGETYPE_GIF, IMAGETYPE_JPEG, IMAGETYPE_PNG, IMAGETYPE_BMP)))
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

**Update2** : Here's a java code chuck link from SO -> [Test if file is an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9643228/test-if-file-is-an-image)

Answer (score 1):

Renaming files only to change case can cause all sorts of trouble. It's even worse when you're dealing with source control systems. And worse again when sharing code between users on case-sensitive systems and those on case-insensitive systems. Not helped by things like Tomcat being case sensitive, even when running on a case-insensitive filesystem.

I wouldn't take a chance. Some potential steps:

- copy the entire project to a new location and open it afresh - see if redeploying from here helps
- move the jpg files into a new directory, or change something else in their names (just one character would be enough) - the idea being to foil any weird name caching issues
- similar idea: rename them all to `.jpeg`

And in future, if you're adjusting the case of filenames, try to do it *before* adding them to your project.

Answer (score 1):

> it's either .jpg to display the .jpg or .JPG to display the .JPG

`.jpg` & `.JPG` represent the same thing (an image in joint photo group format), the difference is in how those files are referenced. Unix based systems (Linux/Mac/etc.) are case sensitive, `'.jpg' != '.JPG'` while Windows ignores case when looking up files,  `'.jpg' == '.JPG'`.

Standardize your file format or update your upload script to accept any case file extension- lower case is best for most conventions.

Comment: Mac filesystems are not case-sensitive by default. And on the other side of the coin, Tomcat on Windows *is* case-sensitive.

Comment: @adam_bear: How do I update my upload script to accept any case file extension? Do you mean within  `web.xml`? Any good example? `:)`

Comment: It could be in the server's `.haccess`, but more likely there is a restriction  on allowed filetypes in the .jsp. `grep JPG *.jsp`would be an easy way to find it.

Answer (score 0):

There's no difference as far as the file format goes, they are exactly the same. The only difference comes when referencing the said file.

For instance, if you were trying to access `image.JPG` and linked it with `src="image.jpg"` you will most likely get a broken link.

*Only difference = When referencing.*

Comment: That's what I thought.  But All the pictures have been renamed to extension `.jpg` but those who were originally with extension `.JPG` wont display... They will display only if I reference as `.JPG`. So are you saying that I should ignore the problem and upload the project to my host without fear?

Comment: @user45678 - first check if those .JPG are valid jpeg files. Open them with a image viewer for an "eye-test". Better to be safe than sorry.

Comment: @MarcoZen: After doing some reseach yesterday, I came accross what it is referred to as "Magic Number" to verify the validity of an image file. Although my mind did not grasp all of it, I think I got the gist of it. If I can understand the subject every file has a serie of characters specific to the system. JPEG image files begin with FF D8 and end with FF D9 for example.

Comment: @MarcoZen: With that knowledge I opened the pictures orginally with .JPG in notepad and discovered the first letters were not the ones expected but these: `MM ` which are the letters for `.TIFF`. I might be wrong but with that deduction I think all .JPG files aren't actually JPEG in the first place... Now how am I supposed to fix this? With a file converter or something? Or can I just change the code of the file to match a JPEG [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29#Magic_numbers_in_files

)?

Comment: @user45678 - where are you getting these jpegs from ? Its better you fix the REAL problem ...

Comment: @user45678 - i have updated my answer to include some code to check if a file is a real image... Pls look for the java equivalent.

Comment: @MarcoZen: Thanks for your answer. I'm sorry I never did that before, where am I supposed to paste the code in my project? `:/`

Comment: @user45678 - use pastebin and stick your code there ? or stick that relevant part here ?