# How to convert bytes to int and compare with value

Tags: java, scala

So I have a value `FFD8FFE0` (jpg/jpeg signature) and I want to check is the uploaded file is jpg/jpeg, but it returns false

```
val param = new FileInputStream(f)
val cnt = param.available
val bytes = Array.ofDim[Byte](cnt)
println(param.read(bytes)==0xFFd8FFe0)
```

Comment: Check for a good solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9643228/test-if-a-file-is-an-image-file

Comment: You are checking the result of the `read` call, not the data that was read. But I already gave you code for this in my answer to your previous question, so please don't keep asking the same question.

Comment: i want to do it using without BufferedInputStream and DataInputStream,only FileInputStream

Answer (score 1):

If you really don't want to use the convenience of
[`DataInputStream.readInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readInt--),
then here is how you can check the first 4 bytes in Java:

```
InputStream stream = new FileInputStream("example.jpg");
byte[] bytes = new byte[4];
stream.read(bytes);
byte[] expectedBytes = { (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0xD8, (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0xE0 };
System.out.println(Arrays.equals(expectedBytes, bytes));
```

and the same in Scala:

```
val stream = new FileInputStream("example.jpg")
val bytes = Array.ofDim[Byte](4)
stream.read(bytes)
val expectedBytes = Array(0xFF.toByte, 0xD8.toByte, 0xFF.toByte, 0xE0.toByte)
println(Arrays.==(expectedBytes, bytes))
```